# Solubility of hydrogen

Tags: aqueous-solution, solubility, hydrogen

I'm interested in bacterial fermentation which produces molecular hydrogen as an end product. If bacteria produce molecular hydrogen in solution under anaerobic conditions, does this remain dissolved in the liquid media or is it likely to be released into the headspace? Would this be affected by oxygen exposure?

Comment: Molecular hydrogen has a boiling point of -253 °C. *Volatile?* It is a gas. And not very soluble in water.

Answer (score 1):

If hydrogen $\ce{H2}$ is an end product in solution, it will soon produce gas bubbles, as the solubility of hydrogen is low : $\pu{1.5 10^{-4}}$ g in $100$ mL at room temperature. This is not affected by oxygen, as both gases are miscible at usual temperatures.

Comment: The idea of mixing O2 into H2 production is disconcerting.